# Share variable across domain and controller in grails

Tags: grails

can i have one variable shared between two classes in grails, like in my controller i want to set a variable processStart as true, and once the after save method is done in my domain class of that controller i want to set it false like this,

```
class EmployeeController{
    def insert() {
         for (i in 1..params.numberOfEmp.toInteger()) {
           Employee emp = new Employee(params)
        processStart = true // set this variable here
        emp.save()
      }
       }
}
```

and in domain class

```
class Employee {
   /** domain structure **/
def afterInsert () {
       processStart = false // and after this, set this variable here
  }
}
```

Comment: What is that variable? Is it a variable per session or per request or per application? You should better store/fetch the variable processStart  to any of these scopes.

Comment: it is a variable per request , i am maintaing a static variable , now it is not executing until one is completed but how do wait and resume in loop

Answer (score 1):

Try using a session variable, you shouldn't do this with a static variable.

```
class EmployeeController{
    def insert() {
        for (i in 1..params.numberOfEmp.toInteger()) {
            Employee emp = new Employee(params)
            session['processStart'] = true // set this variable here
            emp.save()
        }
    }
}
```

and in domain class:

```
class Employee {
    /** domain structure **/
    def afterInsert () {
        session['processStart'] = false // and after this, set this variable here
    }
}
```